# Process part of the regex match before replacing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm writing a function that will parse a file similar to an XML file from a legacy system.

```
....
<prod pid="5" cat='gov'>bla bla</prod>
.....
<prod cat='chi'>etc etc</prod>
....
.....
```

I currently have this code:

```
buf = Regex.Replace(entry, "<prod(?:.*?)>(.*?)</prod>", "<span class='prod'>$1</span>");
```

Which was working fine until it was decided that we also wanted to show the categories.

The problem is, categories are optional and I need to run the category abbreviation through a SQL query to retrieve the category's full name.

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM cats WHERE abbr='gov'
```

The final output should be:

```
<span class='prod'>bla bla</span><span class='cat'>Government</span>
```

Any idea on how I could do this?

Note1: The function is done already (except this part) and working fine. 
Note2: Cannot use XML libraries, regex has to be used

Comment: Why can't you use XML libraries for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` has an overload that takes a `MatchEvaluator`, which is basically a `Func<Match, string>`. So, you can dynamically generate a replacement string.

```
buf = Regex.Replace(entry, @"<prod(?<attr>.*?)>(?<text>.*?)</prod>", match => {
    var attrText = match.Groups["attr"].Value;
    var text = match.Groups["text"].Value;

    // Now, parse your attributes
    var attributes = Regex.Matches(@"(?<name>\w+)\s*=\s*(['""])(?<value>.*?)\1")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .ToDictionary(
                               m => m.Groups["name"].Value,
                               m => m.Groups["value"].Value);

    string category;
    if (attributes.TryGetValue("cat", out category))
    {
        // Your SQL here etc...
        var label = GetLabelForCategory(category)
        return String.Format("<span class='prod'>{0}</span><span class='cat'>{1}</span>", WebUtility.HtmlEncode(text), WebUtility.HtmlEncode(label));
    }

    // Generate the result string
    return String.Format("<span class='prod'>{0}</span>", WebUtility.HtmlEncode(text));
});
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great. I had to "replace match => {" to "delegate(Match match) {" to make it work though.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, this syntax should also work if you want to keep lambda notation: `(Match match) => { ... }`